# SSHTunnel not installed correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, ssh-tunnel

I'm using anaconda python 3.5.2 in PyCharm using windows 10.

I'm pretty new to python and a complete noob to PyCharm!

I just want to use SSHtunnel.

I have intalled the package and it shown in the project interpreter page:

[image]

However when I try to run the code which I cut and pasted from example 1 here https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
'pahaz.urfuclub.ru',
ssh_username="pahaz",
ssh_password="secret",
remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 8080)
)

server.start()

print(server.local_bind_port)  # show assigned local port
# work with `SECRET SERVICE` through `server.local_bind_port`.

server.stop()
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/SSH_Downloader/SSH_Downloader
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/SSH_Downloader/SSH_Downloader", line 1, in <module>
    from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
ImportError: cannot import name 'SSHTunnelForwarder'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

`sshtunnel`  for python and `sshtunnel` Anaconda-python are different modules.

To install `sshtunnel` for Anaconda; you need to use the Anaconda repository. use below `pip` command; Hope this helps:

`pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple sshtunnel`

More Description [Here](https://anaconda.org/pypi/sshtunnel)

Answer (score 0):

I think your name of file is sshtunnel.py

Answer (score 0):

i face this problem on window 10 and fix it buy this line

```
easy_install sshtunnel
```