# python sshtunnel not imported although it already installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, pip

I'm going to connect to mysql database in ec2 linux using python. I would like to using sshtunnel,
but it is not imported although it's installed using "pip install sshtunnel".

When i run python code which is included "from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder",
error message show 
- from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sshtunnel'.

So what should I do for using sshtunnel?

```
import pymysql
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
            '11111111',
            ssh_username="sdgsdgsdg",
            ssh_password="secret",
            remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 22)
        )

        conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', password='11111#', db='Azhi',
                               charset='utf8')
```

Comment: Where/how are you importing sshtunnel? Which python interpreter is being used (what is the output of `which python`)?

Comment: i write the "from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder" on top of code.
I am using pycharm community version.

Comment: Where did you run `pip install` though? Was it inside a virtual environment? It would be helpful if you have access to a terminal where this code is running (assuming linux environment as you are using EC2), to know the output if you type `which python` or `which pip` or even `pip -V`, any of which will tell you more about the version of which Python interpreter and corresponding packages are being loaded when you install with pip and run your code.

Comment: I run pip install in window terminal(local), is not virtual enviornment.

Comment: I am using python 3.8.1, and I want to use like that

import pymysql
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
                '11111111',
                ssh_username="sdgsdgsdg",
                ssh_password="secret",
                remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 22)
            )

            conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', password='11111#', db='Azhi',
                                   charset='utf8')

Comment: But you're not sure which `pip` version installed sshtunnel... is Python3.8 the only Python on your system? what does `pip -V` output? Because if sshtunnel installed correctly via pip, it should be accessible by your Python interpreter. Try doing `pip3 install sshtunnel` and see if that installs it in the `site-packages` for the proper Python verision.

Comment: are you using an anaconda? it looks like similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471364/sshtunnel-not-installed-correctly

Comment: and you also didn't call `server.start()`